# Retrieve first element in a column list and sum over it (e.g. if first element = k, sum over k) in python

Tags: python-3.x, count, sum, pandas-groupby

really sorry if this has been answered already, I'm new to python and might have been searching for the wrong terminology.

I'm working with the US Baby name data as in Python for Data Analysis 2nd ed. Basically I've concated the datasets into a df called name_df looks like

```
id   name   births
1    Aaron  20304
2    Adam    10000
```

etc.

I'm looking to sum over the first letter of each name element if it is a K (or any other letter). I'm struggling to get the first element part though - here is what I have so far:

```
count = 0
letter = ['K']
for n in ['name']:
   if name_df['name'][0] == letter:
        count +=1
    else:
        count+=0

print(count)
```

clearly that just retrieves the first element. do i need to use some sort of splicing technique instead?

Comment: Something like: `name_df['name'].str[0].value_counts()`? What is your desired output here?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to count the distinct names starting with 'K'?

```
len([n for n in name_df['name'] if n[0]=='K'])
```

Or do you want to sum up to get the number of babies?

```
sum([c for n,c in name_df[['name','births']].values if n[0]=='K'])
```

Or with more 'pandaish' syntax:

```
sum(name_df.loc[name_df['name'].str[0]=='K','births'])
```